# Intentionally create a graphical process that does not respond to `_NET_WM_PING`

Tags: signals, window-manager, debugging, strace, testing

Sometimes I am curious how a window manager treats an application that does not respond to [`_NET_WM_PING`](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/wm-spec/1.3/ar01s06.html), e.g. that pop-up that says "[Do you want to terminate this application?](https://superuser.com/questions/1051526/how-to-disable-the-is-not-responding-message-on-fedora/1240861)" This is useful for [debugging](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/200631188-RStudio-starts-occassionally-but-fails-to-start-most-of-the-time) [graphical applications](https://askubuntu.com/questions/412917/how-to-increase-waiting-time-for-non-responding-programs) and understanding how [various applications handle different signals](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=471978) and [different window managers](https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?t=121355) [interact with the application](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=981149).

For example:

- `kwin` has the [`Client::pingWindow()` function](https://github.com/KDE/kwin/blob/40200565323f16e0f30ab80329fb277ca0854edf/client.cpp#L1129), and displays a "[Do you want to terminate this application?](https://github.com/KDE/kwin/blob/40200565323f16e0f30ab80329fb277ca0854edf/helpers/killer/killer.cpp#L103)" message.
- `mutter` has the [`meta_display_ping_window` function](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/mutter/blob/5c27bf6a2b45dde52b00b269c6cd5816dea7fb0f/src/core/display.c#L1987), and displays an "[Application is not responding](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/mutter/blob/master/src/core/meta-close-dialog-default.c#L149)" message.
- `xfwm4` has a [`clientSendNetWMPing` function](https://git.xfce.org/xfce/xfwm4/tree/src/netwm.c?id=5e1354886ae9b22c0fe86ba695ed7f0a63fed14e#n1487), and displays a ["This window might be busy and is not responding"](https://git.xfce.org/xfce/xfwm4/tree/helper-dialog/helper-dialog.c?id=ea1a7115c1e2634d77c5b647cd51b7b0b8b027cb#n94) message.

I would like to intentionally trigger these behaviors, with the ability to run the unresponsive program in `strace` to e.g. see what signals it receives. I am thinking along the lines of a Python/Tkinter or e.g. bash/zenity script, but I am open to other possibilities. Ideally this program would not saturate CPU, but that's not a deal-breaker. (Note that `SIGSTOP` will not trigger the desired behavior from the window manager.)

What's a simple and reliable method to intentionally create a graphical process that does not respond to `_NET_WM_PING` and thereby gets the attention of the window manager?

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do, can you elaborate. I simple way to make it unresponsive is SIGSTOP.

Comment: Did you do anything to make your question cleared, before setting a bounty? Making questions clearer, so we know what you want, is a better way to get good answers.

Comment: I have linked to some relevant code. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor Yes, I have added specifics and additional information, as you can see in the revision history.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a quick and dirty C++ code that creates a window and freezes.

```
// freeze.cpp

#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>
#include <QtWidgets/QMainWindow>
#include <QtCore/QMutex>

int main (int argc, char** argv) {
    QApplication a (argc, argv);
    QMainWindow w;
    QMutex m;
    w.show ();
    m.lock ();
    m.lock ();
    return (a.exec ());
}
```

It depends on Qt5 framework. After installing Qt5 development packages, the code may be compiled by using the following command line (this is not the proper way to build a Qt application, actually):

```
$ g++ freeze.cpp -fPIC -std=c++11 -I/usr/include/qt5 -I/usr/include/qt -lQt5Core -lQt5Gui -lQt5Widgets
```

Comment: Works for me. I needed to add `-I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5` since that's where Ubuntu puts the Qt headers.

Answer (score 3):

The exact answer will depend on the framework etc.

The common "thread" on all the GUI frameworks, is a central/main event handler that receives the events/requests to redraw, keyboard and mouse input etc.

That is then the handler where you can have a event that will not respond back, but sit in a tight `while true; do nothing; done` loop.

Comment: I'm not particular about framework, anything quick and dirty will do.

Answer (score 2):

You could knock out a GUI app in a few lines and wrap it in something that caught your signals. Tkinter with python say is pretty trivial. See [here](http://www.python-course.eu/tkinter_labels.php)

Comment: An actual example would be great.

Comment: @NathanielM.Beaver An actual explanation of what you are trying to do would be better.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `zenity` with any X application of your choice that has the `_NET_WM_PING` property.

```
#!/bin/bash
zenity --question &
sleep 5
kill -STOP $!
```

You'll need to use `kill -CONT xxxx` , replacing `xxxx` with the X application's PID, to allow it to go away.

```
xprop | grep _NET_WM_PING    # Click on the zenity GTK dialog
WM_PROTOCOLS(ATOM): protocols  WM_DELETE_WINDOW, WM_TAKE_FOCUS, _NET_WM_PING, _NET_WM_SYNC_REQUEST
```

Comment: xlogo doesn't have _NET_WM_PING in its WM_PROTOCOLS property, so the wm will not try to use that mechanism with it. Or does it have it? What does xprop | grep PING / click on xlogo say? (I'm on a phone, I cannot check it myself)

Comment: Mmm, it appears `xlogo` indeed doesn't have `_NET_WM_PING`. `zenity` does, though, so I'm replacing with that.

Comment: For me, it just pops up and then goes away after 5 seconds. (Zenity version 3.28.1, Ubuntu 18.04.)

Comment: How are you running it? I'm starting mine from a GUI terminal session with `./script.sh`

Comment: Yep, also running from a GUI terminal with `./script.sh`. I'm on KDE Plasma, though, so I'll try it in XFCE or GNOME some time and see what happens.