# What signal is sent when you kill a program from the "This window might be busy and is not responding..." dialog?

Tags: xfce, xubuntu

In XUbuntu if a program with a GUI window freezes, I might get an alert: "This window might be busy and is not responding.  Do you want to terminate the application?"

What signal is sent to the program if I click to terminate?  Is it sent only to the process that's unresponsive, or is it also sent to all its children, threads or sub-processes or even its parent?  And is the behavior standardized across all Linux distros?

Related question:
[Intentionally create a graphical process that does not respond to `_NET_WM_PING`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/388520/intentionally-create-a-graphical-process-that-does-not-respond-to-net-wm-ping)

Comment: Probably `SIGKILL`. Read `man -a signal`. Child processes are killed as the parent exits.

Comment: @waltinator Child processes are not killed as the parent exits unless the signal is sent to them as well or they are programmed to terminate when their parent dies.

Answer (score 1):

It uses `SIGKILL`, which forcibly terminates any process (except processes in uninterruptible sleep or which are zombies). In order to terminate all child processes under that process, the signal can be sent to all processes in the process group. This is done by specifying a negative PID. For example, if 1234 is unresponsive, it and its children can be killed with `kill(-1234, SIGKILL)`. However, Xfce does not appear to send that signal to the entire process group, only the process with the window.

Note that `SIGKILL` is a heavy-handed way to terminate a process. Unlike most signals, a process that receives the kill signal cannot set up cleanup routines to be executed upon receipt of the signal, so it may terminate while in the middle of writing to a file, causing corruption in that file.

---

In [`helper-dialog/helper-dialog.c:83`](https://gitlab.xfce.org/xfce/xfwm4/-/blob/ba13b17bf2969e3b4284a8d117cba5236f51289f/helper-dialog/helper-dialog.c#L83), we have the message you see:

```
dialog = gtk_message_dialog_new (NULL, 0,
                                 GTK_MESSAGE_WARNING,
                                 GTK_BUTTONS_YES_NO,
                                 _("This window might be busy and is not responding.\n"
                                   "Do you want to terminate the application?"));
```

This dialog is triggered in the function `terminateShowDialog()`, which itself calls the function `terminateProcessIO()`, both defined in [`src/terminate.c`](https://gitlab.xfce.org/xfce/xfwm4/-/blob/ba13b17bf2969e3b4284a8d117cba5236f51289f/src/terminate.c). Then `terminateProcessIO()` calls `clientTerminate()`, defined in [`src/client.c:2730`](https://gitlab.xfce.org/xfce/xfwm4/-/blob/ba13b17bf2969e3b4284a8d117cba5236f51289f/src/client.c#L2730). We can see here that it uses `SIGKILL`:

```
if (kill (c->pid, SIGKILL) < 0)
{
    g_warning ("Failed to kill client id %d: %s", c->pid, strerror (errno));
}
```